# TinyMCE inline option not working?

Tags: tinymce

I have a tinymce 4.7.4 field.

I have applied `inline` option according to the documentation (https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/editor-appearance/) and it returns a js error? So tinymce field breaks.

```
Could not initialize inline editor on invalid inline target element <textarea id="Description" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all input-sm tinymce" cols="20" name="Description" rows="2">
```

The snippet:

```
tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea",
        inline: true,
        toolbar: "undo redo | bold italic | bullist numlist"
        });
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

TinyMCE's inline mode does not work on `<textarea>` elements - it needs to be placed on block elements in the HTML page.

The most common choice would be a `<div>`.  Here is an example:

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/2ggaab

Comment: :Hi,<%= form_with model:@blog,scope: :blog,url:blogs_path, local: true do |form| %> <div class="tinymce">Please type here</div><%= form.submit%><%end%> -> This displays inline tinymce editor. But I want to pass params from view to controller. In classic mode  ,  <%= form.text_area :description, :class => "tinymce" %> -> this code sends the form data to the controller. How can I achieve samething in inline editor mode? Inline editor mode works only with the block elements. I have done a lot of search on this, But didn't find the right solution. Please help me,Thanks in advance.